# How to access array members that are of an interface type c#

Tags: c#

I am a little lost here.

Basically, I need to access an array item, a string and display it.  Here is the code.

```
namespace Test3_2_Practice
{
public partial class InterfaceImplementation : Form
{
    //Array
    ICombatant[] combatants = new ICombatant[2];

    public InterfaceImplementation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        combatants[0] = new PlayerCharacter ("Conan" , 500);
        combatants[1] = new MonsterCharacter ("Bob" , 5);
        combatants[2] = new MonsterCharacter ("Snake" , 15);

        string output = "Fighters" + Environment.NewLine;

        for (var i = 0; i < combatants.Length; i++)
        {
            var character = combatants[i];
            output += "Character:" + combatants[i].
        }
    }
}
```

}

So I have my array, combatants composed of two types of instances.  I want to access the name, "Conan" and add it to a string for output.  How do I go about doing that?  Here is the rest of the code if that helps.  Thanks!

```
namespace Test3_2_Practice
{
//Interface
interface ICombatant
{
    int TakeDamage(int damageAmount);
    string GetHealthDisplay();
}

class PlayerCharacter : ICombatant
{
    private string characterName;
    private int currentHealth;
    private int maxHealth;

    public string CharacterName
    {
        get { return characterName; }
        set { characterName = value; }
    }
    public int CurrentHealth
    {
        get { return currentHealth; }
        set { currentHealth = value; }
    }
    public int MaxHealth
    {
        get { return maxHealth; }
        set { maxHealth = value; }
    }

    public PlayerCharacter(string characterName, int maxHealth)
    {
        CharacterName = characterName;
        CurrentHealth = MaxHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    //Damage Class
    public int TakeDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        if (damageAmount > currentHealth)
        {
            damageAmount = currentHealth;
            return damageAmount;
        }
        else
        {
            currentHealth = currentHealth - damageAmount;
            return damageAmount;
        }
    }

    //Health Class
    public string GetHealthDisplay()
    {
        return ("Health " + CurrentHealth.ToString() + "/" + MaxHealth).ToString();
    }
}

class MonsterCharacter : ICombatant
{
    private string monsterName;
    private int health;

    public string MonsterName
    {
        get { return monsterName; }
        set { monsterName = value; }
    }
    public int Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set { health = value; }
    }

    public MonsterCharacter(string monsterName, int health)
    {
        MonsterName = monsterName;
        Health = health;
    }

    //Damage Class
    public int TakeDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        if(damageAmount > health)
        {
            damageAmount = health;
            return damageAmount;
        }
        else
        {
            health = health - damageAmount;
            return damageAmount;
        }
    }

    //Health Class
    public string GetHealthDisplay()
    {
        return "Health " + Health;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since `name` is common to all implementer of interface that `Name` property should be included to interface itself like

```
interface ICombatant
{
    int TakeDamage(int damageAmount);
    string GetHealthDisplay();
    public string CharacterName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In your current scenario, you will have to cast it specific concrete type before accessing it

```
var character = combatants[i];
if(character is PlayerCharacter)
   output += "Character:" + ((PlayerCharacter)character).CharacterName;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to make a good use of your interface. Create a new method in your interface:

```
interface ICombatant
{
    int TakeDamage(int damageAmount);
    string GetHealthDisplay();
    string GetCombatantName(); // added this
}
```

Then implement in both classes which implements it:

```
class PlayerCharacter : ICombatant
{

    // ... a lot of code ...

    public string GetCombatantName()
    {
        return String.Format("Character: {0}", this.CharacterName);
    }
}

class MonsterCharacter: ICombatant
{

    // ... a lot of code ...

    public string GetCombatantName()
    {
        return String.Format("Monster: {0}", this.MonsterName);
    }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combatants[0] = new PlayerCharacter("Conan", 500);
    combatants[1] = new MonsterCharacter("Bob", 5);
    combatants[2] = new MonsterCharacter("Snake", 15);

    string output = "Fighters" + Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (var combatant in combatants)
    {
        output += combatant.GetCombatantName();
    }
}
```

So if one day you get ten distinct types of `ICombatant` (like AnimalCharacter, VirusCharacter), you don't have to nest a lot of `ifs` to check and cast types to get the proper property.

Interfaces are meant exactly to avoid this kind of stuff, hiding the implementation details.